# Visual Studio Code Angular quickfix import stopped working on particular project

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, intellisense, auto-import

I'm working on Angular 7 app and there is a problem with autoimport via QuickFix.
User defined class and components works fine but the Angulars (like ViewChild, OnInit etc.) are not :/

On clean project it works (I have angular extension for VS Code).

I've tried to find any configuration differences but to be honest what exactly I'm looking for

I've found that there is no *tsConfig* linked in *Angular.json*:

```
"lint": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
      "options": {
        "tsConfig": [
          "tsconfig.app.json"
        ],
        "exclude": []
      }
    }
```

And fix from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55082763/vscode-intellisense-doesnt-suggest-angular-modules-until-imported-manually-in-t) but without success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:
I this situation make sure that your angular dependecies are in you main package.json:

*project/package.json -> angular dependecies*

not in nested library package.json:

*project -> package.json -> lib dependencies -> lib package.json in node-modules -> angular depedencies*

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION FOR THE ISSUE**
it made a tense conditions for me but the site come up and solved the problem easily .Hope you guys enjoy the struggle .

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39488